# Oracle function will not compile

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Following along with oracle docs:  https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/pipelined-table-functions

The "Memory Usage Comparison" section provides the following function, but it fails
to compile with error:  ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_stat (p_stat IN VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER AS
  l_return  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ms.value
  INTO   l_return
  FROM   v$mystat ms,
         v$statname sn
  WHERE  ms.statistic# = sn.statistic#
  AND    sn.name = p_stat;
  RETURN l_return;
END get_stat;
```

The following queries run successfully.

```
select * from v$mystat;
select * from v$statname;

SELECT ms.value
FROM   v$mystat ms,
       v$statname sn
WHERE  ms.statistic# = sn.statistic#
AND    sn.name = 'session pga memory';
```

Additionally, the following anonymous block works correctly.

```
declare
  l_return  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT ms.value
  INTO   l_return
  FROM   v$mystat ms,
         v$statname sn
  WHERE  ms.statistic# = sn.statistic#
  AND    sn.name = 'session pga memory';

  dbms_output.put_line('l_return: ' || l_return);

END;
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

While oracle-base is a very nice site with good tutorial examples, it is most definately *not* "oracle docs".  Those are found at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html.

As for your error, the immediate cause is either 1) the referenced table does not exist, or 2) you do not have permissions on it.  Since the query, outside of the stored procedure, works, we know that the table does exist.  So it is a permissions issue, and this results from the fact that permissions inheretied via a role to not apply in stored procedures.  You'll need to grant the permissions directly to the user.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you acquired privileges to access those tables (views) via **role**. Did you? If so, it won't work in **named** PL/SQL procedures (or functions), but will work in anonymous ones (as you noticed).

In order to make it work in named procedures, you'll have to acquire privileges **directly**.

Answer (score 1):

Some very important topics have been already provided in the answers before, but I want to take time and let me guide you in a test case scenario where you will see why some of your examples work and others don't, when they refer to the same elements ( Oracle V$ Views ), but also you will understand the difference between roles, system privileges and ownership.

**TEST CASE**

I create a test user called `test1` with some basic privileges `create procedure and create table`

```
SQL> create user test1 identified by "Oracle_1" default tablespace tbtest temporary tablespace temp_group account unlock profile default quota unlimited on tbtest;

User created

SQL> grant create table, create procedure to test1;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create table t ( c1 number , c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into t values ( 1 , 1 ) ;

1 row created.
```

Now I am going to create a procedure and a function that will be using v$views. For that , I granted the select any dictionary system privilege to test1.

```
 SQL>  create or replace procedure p
  2  is
  3  n integer;
  4  begin
  5  select count(*) into n from v$session where status = 'ACTIVE' ;
  6* end;
  /

Procedure created.

SQL> create or replace function f_get_count return number
is
n integer;
begin
  select count(*)
  INTO   n
  FROM   v$mystat ms,
         v$statname sn
  WHERE  ms.statistic# = sn.statistic#
  AND    sn.name = 'session pga memory' ;
  return n;
end;
/

Function created
```

So now we have an user that can access the v$ views, as it has been granted with the SELECT ANY DICTIONARY system privilege, shall we check that indeed everything works as expected.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "TEST1"
SQL> select count(*) from v$session ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        62

SQL> select count(*) from v$mystat ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1804

SQL> select count(*) from v$statname ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
      1804
```

Now let's try with the procedures, instead.

```
SQL> select f_get_count from dual ;

F_GET_COUNT
-----------
          1

SQL> exec p ;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

In the case above, the user who runs the procedure is the owner, therefore it is inheriting the execution of its own procedure from the create procedure privilege he was granted. He can also run the procedure and the function succesfullyy, even though contain v$ views, due to the reason that the user has been granted directly the system privilege select any dictionary.

However, the same does not work with the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE.

```
SQL> grant select_catalog_role to test1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> select f_get_count from dual ;
select f_get_count from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06575: Package or function F_GET_COUNT is in an invalid state


SQL> exec p ;
BEGIN p ; END;

      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00905: object TEST1.P is invalid
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

SQL> select count(*) from v$session ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
        63
```

As you can see, the procedure and the function don't work anymore, as a matter of fact they became INVALID. However, the user can still see the tables, as this privilege has been granted by the SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE.

If you grant directly the privilege over v$session, v$mystat and v$statname , everything will back to work as expected.

```
SQL> grant select on v_$mystat to test1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on v_$session to test1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant select on v_$statname to test1 ;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> alter function f_get_count compile ;

Function altered.

SQL> alter procedure p compile ;

Procedure altered.

SQL> exec p;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select f_get_count from dual ;

F_GET_COUNT
-----------
          1
```

If the owner of the procedure is the one executing it, you might granting the select any dictionary system privilege, although I don't recommend it. The granting of this privilege must always be done with extreme care.

Try to grant directly the privileges over the real v$views. The best scenario is creating a dummy/container user who owns the privileges and the procedure, thereby you only need to grant execute over the procedure to the remaining users.

Comment: Roberto -- thank you for the ABSOLUTELY AMAZING answer!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points to upvote.   :-(