# Oracle v$session,v$mystat gives error: table or view does not exist on select

Tags: database, oracle, oracle12c

I have this select statement in a procedure inside a package

`select distinct sid into a from v$mystat;`

`SELECT PADDR,TERMINAL,SID,SERIAL# INTO CURSES,CURTER,CURSID,CURSER  from v$session where sid=a;`

These two statements returns the error

> **PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored, PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

This error is occurring inside procedure but I can run these statements individually from sqlplus or in an sql worksheet in the same user.

I tried to give privilege using grant keyword but gave an error below.  Do you have any possible solution?

[image]

Oracle version: 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should grant select on `v_$session` which is the object behind `v$session` synonym.

Same with `V_$MYSTAT` object for `v$mystat` synonym.

```
GRANT SELECT ON V_$MYSTAT TO <user>

GRANT SELECT ON v_$session TO <user>
```

Comment: this tells the solution, but not the reason for the issue. Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209226/oracle-function-will-not-compile for explanation, why the error occurs.